# symmetric/antisymmetric

Tags: terminology, relations

according to both the text and my professor, these properties are not mutually exclusive.
i.e. a relation can be both symmetric and antisymmetric.

I understand the properties themselves, but I don't understand the reason that one would adopt this naming convention if a relation can have both of these properties.  assuming that the labeling isn't a deliberate attempt to confuse, there must be some deeper reason I don't grasp.  can anyone explain what that would be?

Comment: Sometimes terminology is somewhat contradictory in the natural language. But natural language doesn't matter, what matters is the definition.

Comment: @GitGud I understand that the definition is what matters, and I understand that sometimes labeling can be a bit different from what you'd think it means in common language.  I must not have asked my question clearly enough?  what I would like to know is why choose this naming convention if the symmetric/antisymmetric properties are not mutually exclusive... or to put it another way, what is the reason for not defining the symmetric property in such a way that it excludes the antisymmetric property from applying to said relation.

Comment: I figured you knew this, that's why I left it as a comment. Your question was clear, I wasn't attempting to answer it.

Comment: Can you give an example? I'm not really sure what you are talking about.

Comment: In my opinion these names are good enough. Antisymmetric means something which _destroys/removes symmetry_, and that is exactly what the definition of antisymmetric relation describes, that is, if there is a symmetry, then this symmetry is trivial (i.e. between the element and itself). Observe that any relation which is both symmetric and antisymmetric is a subset of identity, hence not that interesting. Finally, the negation of symmetric is non-symmetric (there is also [asymmetric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymmetric_relation)), I see no contradiction there.

Answer (score 1):

In topology a set can be open, closed or neither open nor closed. So “closed” is not the negation of “open”, which does not agree with common language.

In mathematics what's important are the definitions; the word “antisymmetric” does not denote the negation of “symmetric”, for which “not symmetric” suffices. Perhaps it's not the best terminology, but by now it's standard.

The concept expressed by “antisymmetric” is that you can draw conclusions from the fact that the pairs $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ both belong to the relation, precisely that if this happens, then $a=b$.

Note that “not symmetric” is expressed by existential quantifiers: there exist $a$ and $b$ such that $(a,b)$ belongs to the relation and $(b,a)$ does not belong to the relation. On the contrary, “antisymmetric” is expressed with universal quantifiers: for all $a,b$ in the set, if $(a,b)$ and $(b,a)$ belong to the relation, then $a=b$.

So a relation *can* be both symmetric and antisymmetric. A widely used relation enjoys both properties (see the spoiler below).

> Equality is symmetric and antisymmetric

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer... but I must be really dense, because I still don't understand.  can you explain **why** it's important to be able attribute a relation with both properties?  why isn't it enough to say a relation is strictly one or the other?

Comment: @user147151 They are *different* properties. Some relations have both; but a relation that has both is a subset of the identity relation, so quite irrelevant unless it is the identity itself. It's really not important that a relation has both properties: most relevant relations don't.

Comment: in other words, why isn't relation symmetry defined by the existence of at least some distinct elements aRb implying bRa (a not equal to b)?  is this because we need the empty set to be symmetric for some reason?

Comment: @user147151 Symmetry is “whenever $a\mathrel{R}b$, also $b\mathrel{R}a$, which is very different from your proposed definition.

Comment: thank you for your responses.  I guess for now I'm just going to have to accept that I don't understand the rationale for the way symmetry is defined.  maybe it will become clear eventually.  thanks again.